# datatable select the columns we want dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable with almost 20 columns in it. in another DT i get only the columns I want. Recently my requirements have changed i.e. Firstly the number of columns in the original DT were constant but now it increases or decreases depending upon the data.

So now, if I statically provide the column names I need in my new DT it isnt of much use to me.

Is there any way in which I can include those columns which may or may not be in the Original Datatable????

For eg: col1|col2|col3|.......col20.
The columns that may bve present or absent fall between col12 and col 16. Is there anyway in which I could make it work????

EDIT:
I want col1,col2,col3 and all columns aftr col12...can I do it???

Comment: Can't you add columns dynamically?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. The total number of columns in my Datatableare not stable, I want some columns in a new datatable which are always present in my Main Datatable and others which maybe present or absent in the Main Datatable.

Comment: You can compare column name and add dynamically whatever you need. Would be good if you give one clear example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have total number of columns from datatable using

```
DataTable.Columns.Count
```

So you will know how many columns are there and you will know which column is in datatable and which is not.

Comment: That would be one way to do it but isn't there another subtle and comparatively easy way??? This would require a lot of code. I was kind of hoping for some easy way.

Comment: you said there are only 4 columns which may vary so you can check if these 4 columns are in original dt or not.

Comment: No sir, not 4. These columns come after col12 and they maybe 4 or 5 or even 8. It isn't fixed. That's the main problem. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: ok so you can check count of dt if greater than 12 than you can pick columns which are after column 12 isn't this right ?